# How to pass a component as a prop using Next 13

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-server-components

I have a client component called `Tab`:

```
import * as React from "react";
import type { IconType } from "react-icons";

type TabProps = {
  Icon: IconType;
  label: string;
  isActive?: boolean;
};


export default function Tab({
  Icon,
  label,
  isActive = false,
  ...props
}: TabProps) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Icon size={20} />
      {label}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Whenever I try to use this component, I get this error:
`Functions cannot be passed directly to Client Components unless you explicitly expose it by marking it with "use server"`.

Ok. I have tried wrapping the component passed via `Icon` in a function that makes use of `"use server"` but Next is asking me to enable some experimental flag to make use of the directive.

Is there some way to achieve what I want without going through all of this? I know this was possible in `old` react. Do I need to declare the Icons as client components prior to using them or is there a better solution?

Comment: Can you share the code how do you use your `Tab` component?

Comment: Seems duplicated question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76267974/pass-react-icon-as-props-to-client-component-in-nextjs

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't pass a component from server component to a client component, as it needs to be serializable.

But you can use Slot approach. In your `Tab.tsx`:

```
import React from "react";

type TabProps = {
  Icon: React.ReactElement;
  label: string;
  isActive?: boolean;
};


export default function Tab({
  Icon,
  label,
  isActive = false,
  ...props
}: TabProps) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Icon.type {...Icon.props} size={20}/>
      {label}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Your parent component:

```
<Tab Icon={<Icon/>}/>
```